# How to clear bodycontent of a custom tag?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

How do I clear the body content placed inside a Custom tag?

```
<abc:myTag display="true">

   <b> Clear this content </b>  

<abc:myTag />
```

Based on the display="true" boolean flag in my tag handler, I want to clear out the content **"Clear this content"**. I tried:

```
         if(display){
            getBodyContent();
            } else
            try {
                getBodyContent().clear();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

but its throwing a null pointer exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a reference to the custom element you can do

```
for (Node child; (child = myCustomElement.getFirstChild()) != null;) {
  myCustomElement.removeChild(child);
}
```

If you need to get a reference to the custom element you can do something like

```
Element myCustomElement = myDocument.getElementsByTagNameNS(namespaceForAbc, "myTag");
```

or if you aren't using XML namespaces, you can do

```
Element myCustomElement = myDocument.getElementsByTagName("abc:myTag");
```

Comment: Hi Mick, What would be myDocument here?

Comment: and I am not using XML namespaces.

Comment: `myDocument` would be an instance of `org.xml.Document` produced by your XML or HTML parser.  If you don't have a `Document`, then you can call `getElementsByTagName` on any `Element`.